# Excel to SQL Server From Website (Angular2)

Tags: java, sql-server, excel, angular

im creating a website using angular2,
and want to import file excel and then will be process and input to SQL Server database,

im using express, MSSQL and then i have a code for input like this

```
<input type= "File" >
<button (click)="input()">Submit</button>
```

any suggestion ?

i've try using xlsx java script
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

but still cant figure it out,
any reference or third party lib java script that can be use for my problem?

Comment: Which back-end do you have (ASP, Node, Python) ? Add more details... Do you want to process the excel from browser or back-end ?

Comment: im using node, and process the excel from browser then insert the data to sql server any information you need to know? sorry for the low information

Comment: Install web socket on your nodejs and use it for communicate with server, client side parse the xlsx and call the websocket passing the data, server side (node) get data and insert into MSSQL